# Android Studio: How to integrate Git from Windows 10 Ubuntu bash?

Tags: android, windows, git, bash, shell

Yesterday I installed bash on Windows 10 and also installed Git on it. It works perfectly fine. Following that, I changed the path of the Terminal in Android Studio from "cmd.exe" to "bash.exe" so I can have the bash shell instead of the cmd shell. But now Android Studio cannot find Git (because on Windows it expects a Git.exe) and I would like to know if it is possible to integrate the bash git into Android Studio (just as it does with the Windows .exe version).

Comment: Theoretically yes but it's easier to just use a proper Windows version

Comment: Why is Ubuntu in the topic?

Comment: @Tigger because the Windows 10 bash is called "Ubuntu bash" (it has an underlying Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) you are running a *kind-of* version of Linux. The article says it is a *Windows Subsystem for Linux* which is like the opposite of [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Because of this, you might have more success trying to install the Linux version of everything from the bash shell - including Android Studio.

This way you will not be mixing and matching two System Environments more than what you already have.

Comment: I tried using Xming with WSL to install Android Studio. I got as far as the application attempting to launch but it kept crashing on what looked like access issues. Did you ever get this working?

Comment: actually, not really... a few days after this question I realized that this Ubuntu creates more headaches than it helps, so I kinda abandoned the whole thing...

Answer (score 1):

Try GitWrap
https://github.com/ardevd/gitwrap/releases

This wrapper pipes output from WSL to windows and also works on android studio claimed by the developer